# Meaning of pc in gdb (alias?)

Tags: assembly, gcc, gdb, cpu-registers, program-counter

I have a small x86_64 assembly program and I don't see any register specifically called `pc` (program counter?), though there is the instruction pointer, in the `rip` register However, when I type in:

```
>>> p/x $rip
$15 = 0x4000c5
>>> p/x $pc
$16 = 0x4000c5
```

Both `pc` and `rip` have the same value. Is `pc` an alias to `rip` in gdb, or does it have another meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's GDB's generic name for the Program Counter / Instruction Pointer, whatever target ISA you happen to be debugging.

On x86-64, the architectural register name is RIP, so **`$pc` is an alias for `$rip`**.  Note that this is the address of the next instruction to be executed, i.e. the one you're stopped on.

It's also the same address that RIP had *while* the previous instruction was executing (unless we got here via a branch): RIP-relative addressing is relative to the end of the current instruction (start of the next), same as relative branch displacements.

When execution is stopped in GDB, you can think of this state as being *between* instructions.  The previous instruction is fully finished, but RIP is still pointing at the instruction that's yet to be decoded + executed.  (So `$pc` is actually the exception-return address from the debug exception or single-step TF trap.)

---

On ARM, the instruction-pointer register is called PC or R15, so there it happens that `$pc` actually matches one of the names used in ARM manuals.

I don't know if ARM GDB's `$pc` or `$r15` actually reflects the fact that reading the R15 register with `mov r0, r15` gives you the address of 2 instructions later, not the next instruction like x86-64 `lea rax, [rip + 0]`.

Comment: @old_timer: That's most architectures including x86-64.  RIP is not a general-purpose register, it just has a similar naming scheme.  32-bit ARM is one of the rare ISAs that *does* expose PC as one of the 2^n general-purpose registers.  (I think you know that, maybe you meant to point out the distinction between "architectural" and "general purpose"?)

Comment: @old_timer: Hmm, you just made me wonder whether ARM GDB reads `$pc` and/or `$r15` the same way a `mov r0, r15` instruction would, getting the address of 2 instructions later instead of the next one to execute.  On x86-64, RIP between two instructions is the next one to execute, same as it was during execution of the previous instruction (if it wasn't a branch).  But ARM isn't like that.  I'd guess that GDB would want easy access to the address where you're stopped / instruction that `si` will execute.